# Aurelia Webpack loader unable to find a module I add as a feature

Tags: aurelia

I have a small Aurelia app built with Webpack. Under my **src** folder I have **util** folder with **index.ts** inside. In **main.ts** I turn the feature on like this:

```
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from "aurelia-framework";

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName("util"));
    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app")));
}
```

**util/index.ts**:

```
import { FrameworkConfiguration } from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration): void {
    config.globalResources([
        "./converters",
        "./rest"
    ]);
}
```

**converters** and **rest** are Typescript modules under **util**.

I'm following the instructions from [Aurelia Hub](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/6).

When I open the app in the browser I see the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to find module with ID: util/index
    at WebpackLoader.<anonymous> (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:187)
    at step (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:36)
    at Object.next (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:17)
    at aurelia-loader-webpack.js:11
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.64.__awaiter (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:7)
    at WebpackLoader.webpackJsonp.64.WebpackLoader._import (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:152)
    at WebpackLoader.<anonymous> (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:252)
    at step (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:36)
    at Object.next (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:17)
```

If I reference the modules directly instead of the feature e.g.

```
import { Rest } from '../util/rest';
```

Then I get no errors and the app loads successfully. But I want to have these modules globally available.

Using **aurelia-webpack-plugin** version **2.0.0-rc.2**

Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: This github issue could be useful - https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/issues/96

Comment: No, but I found [this](https://github.com/jods4/aurelia-webpack-build/wiki/Managing-dependencies) and changed in **main.ts** to 
 `.feature(PLATFORM.moduleName("util/index"))`.  Now the browser complains **Unable to find module with ID: util/converters**. So it found **index.ts** under **util** but can't find the modules declared there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this:
https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/blob/master/src/aurelia-templating-resources.js

Edit:

I have gotten it working. The key is that you need to explicitly call `PLATFORM.moduleName('./relative/path/to/file')` on each path specifically and that the call needs to be made from the file (actually technically the same directory but still...) that calls `config.globalResources()`.

In other words you can't shortcut the following code:

```
config.globalResources(
   PLATFORM.moduleName('./resource1'),
   PLATFORM.moduleName('./resource2')
);
```

Don't try to map the resources to PLATFORM.moduleName or to dynamically construct file names.

Comment: Sadly it does not help. Don't know why they import from each. Aurelia documentation of features and their code sample does not mention importing. On the contrary. global resources should allow referencing w/o importing.

Comment: @Benny See my edits to the answer. Also you can look at this comment: https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/issues/107#issuecomment-293878340

Comment: Thanks @pQuestions123. `PLATFORM.moduleName()` helped! I tried it earlier but don't remember why it failed. Now I notice the following: resource **converters** exports a function, resource **rest** exports a class. The result is that **converters** is bundled, but the browser complains about **rest** like so: `Unable to find module with ID: util/rest.html`. Maybe it goes by convention and expects view/view-model. It's another issue that I need to learn about global resources.

Comment: @Benny try adding a `@noView` decorator to your rest.js class.

Comment: Bingo! Lots to learn still, but am enjoying Aurelia. Thanks so much @pQuestions123 :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your path `PLATFORM.moduleName("util")` into PLATFORM.moduleName("./util"). Then you can be able to use path relative to your `util` folder to register your `globalResources`. Also you can look into [here](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/blob/master/doc/article/drafts/Aurelia%20Project%20Structure.md.md) for sample project structure. Also see this [line](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/blob/master/src/framework-configuration.js#L205) of code, aurelia added `/index` to moduleName if it not included as it was based on convention.

If you already try using [aurelia CLI](https://github.com/aurelia/cli), the created project under `src/resources` is registered as a feature.

Comment: `PLATFORM.moduleName("./util")` does not help. I call  `PLATFORM.moduleName("util/index")` now and it recognizes **util** folder but fails to load the resources I call in **util/index.ts**. See my reply to [thebluebox](http://stackoverflow.com/users/297243/thebluefox) above